# Reason behind selection of sites of administration of pituitary extracts?

Tags: zoology, ichthyology

There are two ways by which pituitary extracts are administered in a fish's body during induced breeding of fish.

> Intramuscular injection is the most common practice in India and it is less risky in comparison with the other methods.The extract is injected into the muscle near the tail above the lateral line.
>
> Intra-peritoneal injections are given through the soft regions of the body, generally at the base of the pelvic fin or sometimes at the base of the pectoral fin.

Why are these sites chosen? What physiological effects arise as a result of administration that these sites got chosen ?

Comment: maybe to avoid injecting nerves as it may cause paralysis due to damaged nerves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Intramuscular injections are usually preferred because they result in a more constant delivery of hormone and there is less chance of injuring the fish. The preferred site for an intramuscular injection is into the thick muscle of the back. This is because it is mostly used for fish movement and therefore has the most intensive blood circulation. Thus, injected hormone will be transferred thought the body quickly. Additionally, as this muscle is big, there is smaller chance to injure internal organs by the needle.

Source: assignmentexpert.com

Answer (score 1):

Melatonin is an evolutionary highly conserved molecule that plays an important role in conveying the clock and calendar information to all living organisms, including man. The hormone is synthesized mainly by the pineal gland, and, to a lesser extent, by extrapineal tissues--such as the retina, Harderian gland, and gastrointestinal tract.

It is a standard slow acting hormone injection. Once the injection is in the animal, it just propagates throughout the animal's physiology and takes the normal melatonin chemical and physiological pathways that it does in vertebrates, it prompts the pituitary gland to produce a lot of different hormones including sex and serotonin.

It doesn't act instantaneously if you overdose (humans have tried), OD negative effects occur after 1-2 days and thereafter. It doesn't react as violently as some other hormones such as Adrenaline, which is absorbed fast and dissipates fast and can give you a heart attack. Melatonin has a physiological effect that is more extended, for example steroids for inflammation.

The aim of intramuscular injection of the fish is that it is effective and safe, If you read the guides, they are concerned with the safety of the fish, it's nerves and vital organs... The tail is mostly muscle and the injection is IM. Once the hormone is injected, its absorbed by the animal over an extended period. There have been many experiments of pineal injection in rodents so refer to them to know the time frame of absorption.

Comment: For your kind information the question is about injection of pituitary extract and not pineal extract.        P.S. I didn't read the entire answer but up till the second paragraph.